# ASP MVC HttpPostedFile defined in model class

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

You can define a property of the model as HttpPostedFile? I'm trying and always comes as a null value.
This is the code

```
public class New
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [UIHint("File")]
    public Image ImageHeader { get; set; }

}

public class Image
{
    public string FooterText { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFile File { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(New obj)
    {
        // OK it's populated 
        string FooterText = obj.ImageHeader.FooterText;

        // Error it is not populated! always == null
        HttpPostedFile ImagenFile = obj.ImageHeader.File;

        return View();
    }
```

Is it necessary to create a custom model binder for these cases? Or just the objects(httppotedfile) can be passed as parameters to the controller?

Code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(New obj, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your html code with the form that uploads the file? I am assuming you have a enctype = "multipart/form-data" in your form?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is it necessary to create a custom model binder for these cases?

No. I would recommend you using `HttpPostedFileBase` instead of `HttpPostedFile`:

```
public class New
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [UIHint("File")]
    public Image ImageHeader { get; set; }

}

public class Image
{
    public string FooterText { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new New
        {
            Title = "some title",
            PublishDate = DateTime.Now,
            ImageHeader = new Image
            {
                FooterText = "some footer"
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(New model)
    {
        // everything will be properly bound here
        // see below for the views on how to achieve this
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

a corresponding view (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model New

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Title)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Title)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PublishDate)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.PublishDate)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ImageHeader)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

and the editor template (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/File.cshtml`):

```
@model Image

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.File)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file" })
</div>

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FooterText)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FooterText)
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Darin! Its works! Changing the type of property HttpPostedFileBase filled correctly